# Decrypt Nextcloud Files with Recovery Key

Tags: nextcloud

I have lost my Nextcloud server install, but I have recovered my encrypted files and keys (master, public, and recovery with password).

**I need to decrypt my files.** How would decrypt them without the server?

UPDATE: I have a dump of the database. I don't have the user's personal keys (but I do have the password).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.

Your best bet is to recover your decrypted files synced to another computer from the server.